# Could I download the event log from the firebase console?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

Flurry provides event log download button. But I've found none button in the firebase console to download the event log.

Or do I must integrate the google cloud BigQuery with firebase to get the raw log events?

Comment: Not sure, but this might answer it: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-talk/S0Mrwq_UsgU/qUoju3VnAAAJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that Flurry's event log download provides access to aggregate data whereas BigQuery provides access to Firebase Analytics' raw events, parameters and user properties.

Firebase Analytics does not yet offer an option to download aggregate data.

Comment: Yes, Flurry provides access to the latest log data which is always about 14MB.

Comment: Here is a nice script to get you started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45920753/raw-bigquery-log-data-for-1st-day-installers/45922099#45922099